# Countability of the preimages of a real valued function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am not sure how to do the following question:

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined for every $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$.
>   Suppose there is a positive number $M$ having the following property: for every choice of
>   a finite number of points $x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$ in the interval $(0,1)$, the sum $| f(x_1) + ... + f(x_n) | \leq M$ holds.
>
> Let $S$ be the set of those $x \in (0, 1)$ for which $f(x) \neq 0$. Prove that $S$ is countable.

Comment: Hint: an uncountable set of real numbers has a non zero limitpoint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\{x\mid f(x)\ne 0\} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_+} \{x\mid |f(x)|>\tfrac1n\}$$ and each of the sets on the right-hand side must be finite.

Comment: I don't get why is each set on the right finite?

Comment: @JunaidAftab: If one of them is infinite, then it must contain either infinitely many _positive_ values or infinitely many _negative_ values. Suppose there are infinitely many positive values. Then adding up $nM$ of them would give a sum larger than $M$, contradicting your assumption. (The case for infinitely many negative values is exactly similar).